# How do I format a Windows D drive that previously had Windows installed on it?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, formatting

I'm currently using a Windows 10 desktop PC, and I ran out of storage on my C drive. To upgrade my storage, I installed an old hard drive of mine in the desktop, which I would like to use as a D drive. When I browse its files, I can see that there's an existing installation of Windows on the drive. I don't care about any of the files on it; I just want to wipe the drive clean and start over. That said, when I try to format the drive I get an error saying that the drive is in use. According to Task Manager, I don't currently have anything accessing the drive. What's the easiest way to wipe the disk and start over?

Comment: Use Windows disk management to format the drive

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is probably:

- open disk management
- try to delete the partition
- create new partition and format it

if deleting the partition doesn’t work, right click on the left of the disk, and select 'offline' and restart Windows. After restart, do the same as above, but bring the disk online again before deleting the partition on it. At this point, you could also try simply reformatting it.

Because the disk is brought online only at this very moment in time, Windows should not use the disk otherwise, and re-formatting should succeed.

If nothing helps, I usually do the following: use a disk hex editor, and clear the first sector of the disk. This first sector is never protected by Windows – as opposed to a 1st sector of a partition – so you can delete the first sector. After restart, the disk will then be seen as new.

Answer (score 1):

- Unmount the drive before tring to format it.
- The drive might be in use by Windows Defender or Windows Search Indexer. To see what is locking the drive try a utility such as [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/), which may be able to unlock the drive so that you can use Windows *diskmgmt.msc* or a third-party tool such as [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) to format it.
- Another option is to boot from USB drive, *without mounting the HDD*, and use tools on the boot drive, such as Ubuntu's *Disk Utility*, which comes with [Ubuntu Live](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), or a tool such as [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), which includes a number of disk management tools.

**N.B.** Be *verrrry* sure you're formatting the correct drive... not accidentally wiping the main drive.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to File Explorer and Disk Management that has been mentioned above, DiskPart is another option you could try.
Launch Command Prompt, enter diskpart > list disk > sel disk x (the number of the old disk you want to format) > clean. If you want to make the delete data unrecoverable, use "clean all" command instead (Check [clean a hard drive in Windows 10](https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/clean-a-hard-drive-windows-10-1021.html) for more details).

This could be done either inside Windows or from advanced boot options. Thus even if you want to format the current boot drive, you can do it without login to Windows.

Of course, you can also turn to some professional erase tools for more powerful wiping methods.